# Не могу настроить вывод информации на форму через DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Я написал свою програмку(Cапер), но у меня не выводит данные из файла в DataGridView. Данные записываю в класс, а объекты класса записываю в List. Потом провожу сериализацию(в основной форме) и десериализацию в форме, где вывожу таблицу рекордов.
Программа работает, игра - играется, компиляор - не ругается. Единственное, что не так: то-ли вывод данных в таблицу не работает, то ли класс данные не собирает и не записывает. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Во код основной формы:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.IO;

namespace Minesweeper
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int height = 7; 
    int width = 7;  
    int distanseBetweenButtons = 22;
    ButtonExtended[,] allButtons;
    int amount_buttons;
    int EmptyCell;
    Data_achievements result = new Data_achievements("", "", "");
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GenerateField();
    }
    void GenerateField ()
    {
        groupBox1.Text = width.ToString() + " x " + height.ToString();
        stopWatch.Start();
        result.sizeOf_Field = width.ToString() + "x" + height.ToString();//** size of field remembering
        amount_buttons = height * width;
        int numerator_mineOrNot = 0;
        allButtons = new ButtonExtended[width, height];
        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int x = 10; (x - 10) < width * distanseBetweenButtons; x += distanseBetweenButtons)
        {
            for (int y = 20; (y - 20) < height * distanseBetweenButtons; y += distanseBetweenButtons)
            {
                ButtonExtended button = new ButtonExtended();
                button.Location = new Point(x, y);
                button.Size = new Size(21, 21);
                if (rng.Next(0, 101) < 20)
                {
                    button.isBomb = true;
                    numerator_mineOrNot++;
                }
                allButtons[(x - 10) / distanseBetweenButtons, (y - 20) / distanseBetweenButtons] = button; //We put our created buttons in array
                groupBox1.Controls.Add(button); 
                //creating field and checking on mine

                EmptyCell = amount_buttons - numerator_mineOrNot;

                button.Click += new EventHandler(FieldClick);
            }
        }
    }
    void FieldClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EmptyCell--;
        //function which will call with each click on button
        ButtonExtended button = (ButtonExtended)sender;
        if(EmptyCell == 0)// win condition
        {
            EmptyFieldClick(button);
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    if (allButtons[x, y].isBomb)
                    {
                        allButtons[x, y].Text = "*";
                    }
                }
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            TimeSpan result_time = stopWatch.Elapsed;
            result.time = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", result_time.Hours, result_time.Minutes, result_time.Seconds);
            request Request_form = new request();
            Request_form.Show();
            Achievements_recording(result);
            Disactiveted();
        }
        if(button.isBomb == true)
        {
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Explode(button);
        }
        else
        {
            EmptyFieldClick(button);
            button.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    void Explode(ButtonExtended button)
    {

        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                if (allButtons[x,y].isBomb)
                {
                    allButtons[x, y].Text = "*";
                }
            }
        }
        Disactiveted(); 
        MessageBox.Show("You lose!");
    }
    void EmptyFieldClick(ButtonExtended button)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
              if(allButtons[x,y] == button)
              {
                    button.Text = "" + CountBombsAround(x, y);
              }
            }
        }
    }

    int CountBombsAround (int xB, int yB)
    {
        int bombsCount = 0;
        for (int x = xB - 1; x <= xB + 1 ; x++)
        {
            for (int y = yB - 1; y <= yB + 1; y++)
            {
                if(x >= 0 && x < width && y >= 0 && y < height)
                {
                    if(allButtons[x, y].isBomb)
                    {
                        bombsCount++;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return bombsCount;
    }

    private void x10ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Activeted(); 
        groupBox1.Controls.Clear(); 
        //size for form (255; 300)
        width = 7;
        height = 7;
        GenerateField();
    }

    private void x5ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Activeted(); 
        groupBox1.Controls.Clear(); 
        //size for form (190; 228)
        width = 10;
        height = 10;
        GenerateField();
    }

    private void x15ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Activeted(); 
        groupBox1.Controls.Clear(); 
        //size for form (365; 405)
        width = 15;
        height = 15;
        GenerateField();
    }

    void Disactiveted () 
    {
        groupBox1.Enabled = false;
    }

    void Activeted () 
    {
        groupBox1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void рекордиToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//**
    {
        Form2 _achievements = new Form2();
        _achievements.Show();
        _achievements.Size = new Size(250, 250);
    }

    void Achievements_recording(Data_achievements results)//**
    {
        List<Data_achievements> recording = new List<Data_achievements>();
        using (request userNAME = new request())
        {
            result.user_name = userNAME.userName;
        }
        recording.Add(results);

        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        // Запись
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream("Minesweep_result.bin", FileMode.Create))
        using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            formatter.Serialize(zipStream, recording);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Вот код класса, который собирает данные:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Minesweeper
{
[Serializable]
class Data_achievements
{
    private string User_name { get; set; }
    private string Time { get; set; }
    private string SizeOf_Field { get; set; }

    public string user_name { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
    public string sizeOf_Field { get; set; }

    public Data_achievements (string user_name, string time, string sizeOf_Field)
    {
        this.user_name = user_name;
        this.time = time;
        this.sizeOf_Field = sizeOf_Field;
    }

}
}
```

Здесь код формы которая выплывает при победе и запрашивает имя игрока:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Minesweeper
{
    public partial class request : Form
    {
        public string userName
        {
            get { return textBox1.Text; }
        }


    public request()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
    }
}
}
```

А здесь код формы, которая десериализирует файл и выводит данные в DataGridView:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.IO;

namespace Minesweeper
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        void data_output()
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            List<Data_achievements> gift = new List <Data_achievements>();
            // Чтение
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream("data.bin", 
FileMode.Open))
        using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            gift = (List<Data_achievements>)formatter.Deserialize(zipStream);
        }

        //create table with name: "Results"
        DataTable table = new DataTable("Результати");

        //create objects DataColumn
        var user_name = new DataColumn("Ім'я");
        var time = new DataColumn("Час");
        var field = new DataColumn("Поле");

        //add objects DataColumn in DataTable
        table.Columns.Add(user_name);
        table.Columns.Add(time);
        table.Columns.Add(field);

        //for each elements add row in table
        foreach (Data_achievements results in gift)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row["Ім'я"] = results.user_name;
            row["Час"] = results.time;
            row["Поле"] = results.sizeOf_Field;
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Вы знаете что такое дебаг (отладка)?  Так вот очень сильно советую ей воспользоваться. Поставьте точку остановки в месте `то-ли вывод данных в таблицу не работает` и `то ли класс данные не собирает и не записывает` и поглядите какие вы данные получаете и записывайте, записываются ли они вообще и так далее. А то гадаете на кофейной гуще...

Comment: Я допустим вижу сразу чтение: `using (var fileStream = new FileStream("data.bin", FileMode.Open))` запись: `using (var fileStream = new FileStream("Minesweep_result.bin", FileMode.Create)`. Не смущает нечего?

Comment: Простите, я просто впервые с файлами, сериализацией и таблией этой работаю, очень мало что понимаю и уже более сконцентрирован на ошибки по незнанию, чем на невнимательности. Но разве отладчик выдаёт это за ошибку? Да есть немного. А что скажете по способу вывода данных в таблицу?

Comment: `отладчик выдаёт это за ошибку?` - я нечего не говорил про ошибку, я лишь сказал что если вы сомневаетесь в каком то месте кода, то просто поставьте туда точку остановки и посмотрите какие данные туда "залетают" и дальше смотрите почему такие данные там. В вашем случае скорей всего данных не было бы вовсе, начали бы смотреть и увидели бы, что имя файла то другое указано. `А что скажете по способу вывода данных в таблицу?` - Этот вопрос не ко мне. Я считаю `WinForms` устарелым и очень давно его забросил. Поэтому я не знаю, актуален ли там сейчас такой подход. В `WPF` я бы за такое по рукам бил!

Comment: Жаль, но спасибо, что и на это указали.